# How to prevent CaseTeamMember creation for Customer Community Plus License

Tags: trigger, case-teams, customer-community-plus

Because there are no options yet to trigger on CaseTeamMember object, we don't have a path forward to prevent the insertion of a user based on profile. When performing the same functionality with the lower license Customer Community license, we see an error saying that the user type does not allow for such creation. This would be the desired behavior we would like to see for the Customer Community Plus Users.

Error for Customer Community License
[image]

As of right now, just because of the license it just creates the team member, no issue:
Success for Customer Community Plus License
[image]

This is an issue for us because we use Salesforce for IDP purposes and this is opening records that customers shouldn't see because the support reps are picking the wrong users in the dropdown.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with the restrictions on cases but perhaps you could replace the standard button with a custom button? If so, then a short flow may allow you to check the user licence before inserting the record.